# SqlAlchemy orm query alternative for async session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Previously, when I used sync session, I could query mapped models to tables; being mapped imperative or declarative made no difference. given as an example:

```
mapper_registry = sqlalchemy.orm.registry()

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class MissionStatus:
    uuid: UUID
    name: str
    order: int

missions_status = Table(
    "mission_status",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column(
        "uuid",
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        unique=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    ),
    Column("name", String, nullable=False),
    Column("order", Integer, nullable=False),
)
```

and my mapper starter would do:

```
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    model.MissionStatus,
    missions_status,
)
```

and I could simply do something like this:

```
my_missionstatus = session.query(MissionStatus).filter(MissionStatus.order=1).first()
```

doing this is beneficial in ways which is not my point here. my problem is when I decided to use async session instead and `.query` doesn't work as before. It throws `'AsyncSession' object has no attribute 'query'` and searched for a work-around but haven't figured it out. Is there anything I could do about it?
I'm using this deps:

```
SQLAlchemy==1.4.41
asyncpg==0.27.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. the author is using a table class which is not my case. my class is completely independent to database, but that post's `TableClass` isn't and is using declarative mapping